# How to use SaveFileDialog asynchronously?

Tags: winforms, asynchronous, savefiledialog

I have a windows forms application, with a button - on the button's event handler, I need to download a file with SaveFileDialog. But I need to do this asynchronously on a separate thread.

So far, I came up with this code, but I don't know if my approach is flawed or OK:

```
        private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                ThreadStart tStart = new ThreadStart(DoWorkDownload);
                Thread thread = new Thread(tStart);
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
        }

        private void DoWorkDownload()
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            sfd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
            sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
            sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            //do file saving here
            }
        }
}
```

My logic in the code above is: on button click create a new thread, pass the DoWorkDownload() method to the thread, and then start it; at that moment it is supposed to enter the work method - however, when debugging it never enters DoWorkDownload().

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Main application thread was also started in STA mode?

Comment: Bogdan_Ch, that is correct: my code above was written in Form1.cs and the project also includes Program.cs which has [STAThread] for Main. Should I not use STA in my declaration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BackgroundWorker](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-introduction), which is easy to use.

Also, I'm not sure it's completely safe (I could be wrong, though) to show the SaveFileDialog in the new thread. My recommendation would be a flow as such:

1. Show SaveFileDialog on main thread.
2. Pass file name to a method, which is then called asynchronously.

Here's an example implementation, without the use of `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
  sfd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
  sfd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
  sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
  sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;
  if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    // Invoke the SaveFile method on a new thread.
    Action<string> invoker = new Action<string>(SaveFile);
    invoker.BeginInvoke(sfd.FileName, OnSaveFileCompleted, invoker);
  }
}

protected void SaveFile(string fileName)
{
  // save file here (occurs on non-UI thread)
}

protected void OnSaveFileCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
  Action<string> invoker = (Action<string>) result.AsyncState;
  invoker.EndInvoke(result);
  // perform other actions after the file has been saved (also occurs on non-UI thread)
}
```

Note that all actions performed on non-UI threads, must only affect non-UI elements. If you want to modify UI elements, you should marshal the call back to the UI thread, by using `Control.Invoke` (e.g. `this.Invoke`). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194918/why-am-i-getting-a-cross-thread-operation-not-valid-exception-in-the-callback-m/1194997#1194997) for further details.

Comment: In my case it works either with BackgroundWorker or with ThreadStart.

Comment: Thank you for the code but what exactly is "Action", is it a custom type you have built for this purpose? Could you please give me a hint on how I can implement that?

Comment: I haven't built it, no. System.Action<T> is a generic delegate type in .NET, which is used for invoking methods which return _void_ and takes one parameter of type _T_, e.g. void SaveFile(string fileName), where _T_ in this case is _string_.

Comment: It became available in .NET 2.0, so if you're using .NET 1.1, you'll have to define your own delegate and use it instead of Action<T>

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that StackOverflow replaced the <string>-part of the Action declaration. I've updated the answer to show the full code.

Answer (score 2):

In my case debugger DO enters DoWorkDownload()
It enters after the end of btnDownload_Click()
Set breakpoint on SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();  and it should work

In order to prove that it works asynchronously I even put the following code

```
ThreadStart tStart = new ThreadStart(DoWorkDownload);
Thread thread = new Thread(tStart);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();

Thread.Sleep(10000);
MessageBox.Show("qwe");
```

and run without debugger and you will see that when current thread is going to sleep, SaveFileDialog will appear... and only after 10 seconds a message box will be shown

Answer (score 1):

Bernhof might be right, however, be careful. All UI elements should execute on the same thread. So if you create a new thread for the SFD, make sure you don't update any control on your main window.

Kind regards,
Guillaume Hanique

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but since i had this same problem, i want to share my solution for modern times:
The fix is simply to call the Dialog before the 'await Task.Run(()':

```
public async Task<string> DownloadFile(string pFilter = "MyNotes document|*.note|All Files|*.*", string pDefaultExt = "note")
{
    string _ret = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (FilesRequest != null)
        {
            SaveFileDialog SFDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
            {
                Filter = pFilter,
                FilterIndex = 0,
                DefaultExt = pDefaultExt,
                AddExtension = true,
                CheckPathExists = true,
                OverwritePrompt = true,
                FileName = FileData.Name,
                InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            };

            if (SFDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    DownloadedFilePath = SFDialog.FileName;
                    using (var download_stream = new System.IO.FileStream(SFDialog.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        var DS = FilesRequest.DownloadWithStatus(download_stream);
                        if (DS.Status == Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Completed)
                        {
                            _ret = SFDialog.FileName;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _ret = DS.Status.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return _ret;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
this.FilePath = await API.DownloadFile();
```